# Quasiconvex and quasiconcave graphs

Tags: analysis, functions, graph-theory

Can anyone show the difference between quasiconvex, quasiconcave and quasilinear graphs? I am confused, because all quasiconvex graphs seem to be quasilinear...

Comment: There are several definitions of quasiconvexity in the literature. Could you please tell us which one you are referring to?